# Можно ли на wordpress вынести по разным пунктам админ меню посты различающиеся по ключу?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть зарегистрированный кастомный тип записи `lesson` на **wordpress**.

На сайте использую 2 типа занятий одиночные ($single_lesson) и повторяющиеся ($repeater_lesson), которые различаются выбранным в [advanced custom fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) ключом `lesson_single`.

**Код function.php**

```
//регистрация типа записи
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_cpt' );
function register_my_cpt() {
    register_post_type('lesson', array(
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog',
        'label'  => 'Занятия',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'lesson', 
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' )
    ));
    }
```

В админке и одиночные и повторные события выводятся в потоке все вместе общим списком, что не удобно отслеживать и редактировать. 
Есть ли возможность их разделить по разным пунктам админ меню так, чтобы не пересекались между собой или это возможно только с помощью регистрации нового типа записей? Если да, то как?

```
    //вывод
    $single_lesson = new WP_Query( array ( 
        'post_type' => 'lesson', 
        'posts_per_page' => '-1', 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
        'post_status' => array( 'future' ),
        'meta_query' => array( 
            array(
                'key' => 'lesson_single', 
                'value' => '1'
            )
        )
    ) );

        $repeater_lesson = new WP_Query( array ( 
            'post_type' => 'lesson', 
            'posts_per_page' => '-1', 
            'order' => 'ASC', 
            'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'future' ),
            'meta_query' => array( 
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'lesson_single', 
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'lesson_single', 
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '!=',
                    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                )
            )
        ) );
```

Comment: Их надо не примочкой типа ACF разносить, а таксономией. Тогда в админке будет всё в порядке.

Comment: @KAGG Design т.е., новую таксономию ввести? поясните.
Уже есть такая примока и более того под это дело настроен календарь с опциями и прописано с 20к занятий. Вопрос теперь только в том как разнести

Comment: ну да, надо таксономию под тип занятий и фильтр таксономий в админку: https://generatewp.com/filtering-posts-by-taxonomies-in-the-dashboard/

Comment: @KAGG Design спасибо, буду пробовать, по итогу отпишусь